# Retrieve all headlines from a pdf document with iText

Tags: java, itext

I try to read a pdf document and extract all headlines which are in the pdf document.
Example of the headlines:

1 Title

1.1 Title Example 1

1.2 Title Example 2

1.2.1 Title Example 3

For that i use iText. Anay ideas how I can retrieve the headlines?
Thank you

```
PdfReader = new PdfReader((new FileInputStream(systemResource.getFile())));
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);

for(int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
            TextExtractionStrategy simpleTextExtractionStrategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            simpleTextExtractionStrategy.getResultantText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially 2 groups within the PDF standards that are available.

- Tagged : The PDF document contains meta-information that helps in identifying the structure of a document (paragraphs, sections, header, footer, table, list, etc)
- Untagged : The PDF document contains only instructions for a viewer to be able to render the page.

  e.g :

  - move the cursor to 50, 50
  - set the font to Helvetica, size 12
  - draw the glyph for character 'H'
  - etc

  If your PDF document is tagged, it will be easy to retrieve the document structure (and thus your headers).

If the PDF document is untagged, you would need to write your own custom logic to identify text-chunks (the raw data being given to `IEventListener`). You'd need to merge those chunks into lines (based on some heuristic). And then you'd be able to identify headers (using heuristics like 'starts with a number' or 'the font is typically larger than the average font size on the page, etc)